# Reusing react component duplicates DOM elements

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-component

I have created a React component which opens a form for input parameters and once the form is submitted, a call is made to server and the resulting json is displayed in the UI. This component takes input parameters from dropdown, text box and so on.

So I created a generic component as there are many such instances. I passed the required input through props and displayed the values in the component dynamically.

When I called the second component's instance passing the values, I see that opening the dropdown in the first instance, opens the dropdown from second instance.

Please suggest an approach to make each component's instance unique.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redux store could be used ... It would be better if you could share the demo where exactly there is problem

Comment: Sorry I couldn't share my code as I'm working on a banking application. I will try to create a sample component to explain the issue. Basically the issue is when I open the dropdown in one component it opens the same dropdown in another component as the class names are same.